# using prerender.io to cache article page with a fragment identifier

Tags: seo, single-page-application, angular.js

my website is running on SPA Angular 7. Currently, I am using prerender.io to cache the front page (`/#/home`) without problem.

my question is, I want prerender.io to cache my article page which shows dynamic article contents based on article id supplied under the URL query string. e.g. `www.example.com/#/article?id=5`

how do I ensure all article contents/pages are cached? do I have to add evey URL with fragment identifier id (`?id=1`, `?id=2` so on) into prerender.io dashboard?

Comment: You had originally said "query string" in your question, but everything in the URL after the `#` is the fragment identifier.  Your URLs don't have query strings.  A query string would have to be a `?` before the `#`.

Comment: but in my case query string is after #.. but let's say if change my Angular config not to use hash as the location strategy, yet, how do I still deal with query string for prerender io?